# Minimize developer tools window while debugging a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am new to chrome extensions. When I right click on the extension icon and click on 'Inspect Popup' option, the developer tools window opens up and is maximized (full screen).

What I want is to minimize the developer tools window so that I can view my popup, opened as well.

Comment: The developer tools window is like any other window of your OS. Minimize it with the controls usualy on the top bar (left side in OS X / macOS, right side in Windows or Linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are saying "minimize the developer tools window",

1. If you mean `minimize`, then as @Iván Nokonoko said, you could just minimize it with the controls on the top bar
2. I guess you mean `dock the developer tools bottom`, if you mean that, it's not allowed to dock popup types window at present, see [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=560023) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Haibara Ai . Option 2 was what i was looking for.